# How can I easily transform an input string using gsub with a regex?

Tags: regex, ruby

I am trying to come up with a nice way to perform interpolation/translations on a string that will be used as a query for a search engine.

I came up with this regex to try to use named capture groups to help make sense of things, and not only is it really gross, it's got a few problems...

```
REGEX = /\[(?<range>[^\]]+)\]|"(?<quoted_value>[\w\s]+)"(?<operator>(?:\sOR\s|\sAND\s))?|(?:\(|\))*(?<key>\w+):(?:\()*(?<value>[\w]+)(?:\))?(?<operator>(?:\sOR\s|\sAND\s))?|(?:\(|")*(?<value>[\w]+)(?:\()*(?<operator>(?:\sOR\s|\sAND\s))?/)
```

The plan is to use this regex with gsub, and in a block modify the matches as necessary-- so something like:

```
  
  def fancy_input_changer
    input.gsub(REGEX) do |match|
      key = Regexp.last_match[:key]
      match.sub(key, translation_for_key(key)) if key
      # etc...
    end
  end

  ...

  def translation_for_key(key)
    case key
    when 'cat'
      'kitty_cat'
    #  ...etc
    end
  end
```

So, for the given (ridiculous) test input:

```
"((brick OR broom OR lettuce) AND \"plunk your magic twanger froggy\" AND frogger AND (cat:(meow OR \"purr loudly\" OR scratch) OR dog:\"woof\" OR range:[1 TO 25] OR (zebra:\"stripes\" OR horse:\"neigh\"))) OR (just:about AND anything:else)"
```

If I inspect `Regexp.last_match` within each block call from gsub, I see:

```
[#<MatchData "((brick OR " range:nil quoted_value:nil operator:nil key:nil value:nil operator:nil value:"brick" operator:" OR ">,
 #<MatchData "broom OR " range:nil quoted_value:nil operator:nil key:nil value:nil operator:nil value:"broom" operator:" OR ">,
 #<MatchData "lettuce" range:nil quoted_value:nil operator:nil key:nil value:nil operator:nil value:"lettuce" operator:nil>,
 #<MatchData "AND" range:nil quoted_value:nil operator:nil key:nil value:nil operator:nil value:"AND" operator:nil>,
 #<MatchData "\"plunk your magic twanger froggy\" AND " range:nil quoted_value:"plunk your magic twanger froggy" operator:" AND " key:nil value:nil operator:nil value:nil operator:nil>,
 #<MatchData "frogger AND " range:nil quoted_value:nil operator:nil key:nil value:nil operator:nil value:"frogger" operator:" AND ">,
 #<MatchData "(cat:(meow OR " range:nil quoted_value:nil operator:nil key:"cat" value:"meow" operator:" OR " value:nil operator:nil>,
 #<MatchData "\"purr loudly\" OR " range:nil quoted_value:"purr loudly" operator:" OR " key:nil value:nil operator:nil value:nil operator:nil>,
 #<MatchData "scratch" range:nil quoted_value:nil operator:nil key:nil value:nil operator:nil value:"scratch" operator:nil>,
 #<MatchData "OR" range:nil quoted_value:nil operator:nil key:nil value:nil operator:nil value:"OR" operator:nil>,
 #<MatchData "dog" range:nil quoted_value:nil operator:nil key:nil value:nil operator:nil value:"dog" operator:nil>,
 #<MatchData "\"woof\" OR " range:nil quoted_value:"woof" operator:" OR " key:nil value:nil operator:nil value:nil operator:nil>,
 #<MatchData "range" range:nil quoted_value:nil operator:nil key:nil value:nil operator:nil value:"range" operator:nil>,
 #<MatchData "[1 TO 25]" range:"1 TO 25" quoted_value:nil operator:nil key:nil value:nil operator:nil value:nil operator:nil>,
 #<MatchData "OR" range:nil quoted_value:nil operator:nil key:nil value:nil operator:nil value:"OR" operator:nil>,
 #<MatchData "(zebra" range:nil quoted_value:nil operator:nil key:nil value:nil operator:nil value:"zebra" operator:nil>,
 #<MatchData "\"stripes\" OR " range:nil quoted_value:"stripes" operator:" OR " key:nil value:nil operator:nil value:nil operator:nil>,
 #<MatchData "horse" range:nil quoted_value:nil operator:nil key:nil value:nil operator:nil value:"horse" operator:nil>,
 #<MatchData "\"neigh\"" range:nil quoted_value:"neigh" operator:nil key:nil value:nil operator:nil value:nil operator:nil>,
 #<MatchData "OR" range:nil quoted_value:nil operator:nil key:nil value:nil operator:nil value:"OR" operator:nil>,
 #<MatchData "(just:about AND " range:nil quoted_value:nil operator:nil key:"just" value:"about" operator:" AND " value:nil operator:nil>,
 #<MatchData "anything:else)" range:nil quoted_value:nil operator:nil key:"anything" value:"else" operator:nil value:nil operator:nil>]
```

A lot of this is doing what I want, but with this example, "dog", "zebra", and "horse" are incorrectly captured as a value instead of a key..  Also a few "OR"s are incorrectly captured as a value instead of an operator...

Question 1:
Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?  I need to perform certain transforms on keys and values..   A user may input something like `foo bar` and i need to  turn it into `name:(foo OR bar) AND title:(foo OR bar)` or ever more extremely, a user may input something like `foo:bar` and I need to turn it into `((foo:bar OR fooey:"baz bar") AND lol:"wut lol!")` .. so this can end up getting very complex.

Question 2:
Is there a way to simplify my regex?  I am reusing certain components multiple times like `(?<operator>(?:\sOR\s|\sAND\s))`  ...  I was hoping I could use "backreferences" to reuse the same components like `...|...\k<operator>...` but that does not seem to work, so I had to reuse it.  I could store it in a variable as a string and interpolate that, but am wondering if there is a way to do it within the regex?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. I suggest you begin with a statement of your problem. It's often helpful, as it would be here, to include an example that includes the desired return value. Make the example as concise as possible while retaining all the essential elements of the problem.

Comment: If there are no limitations for the input string (so it can be literally any valid predicate with arbitrary nesting of the conditional branches) I'd say you are dealing with non-regular language and regexp is not the tool for the job. I'd go with the custom parser that would parse your input into some simple AST and a simple tree-walking "interpreter" that would do all the interpolations that you need.